# changing bootstrap NavDropDown.Item's active background color with reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

please consider the following snippet:

```
<NavBar>
    <!-- some stuff here -->
    <Navbar.Collapse>
        <!-- some other stuff here -->
        <Nav>
            <NavDropdown title="Mon compte" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                <Link to='/login'>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as='span' className='text-center'>Connexion</NavDropdown.Item>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/register'>
                    <NavDropdown.Item as='span' className='text-center'>Inscription</NavDropdown.Item>
                </Link>
            </NavDropdown>
        </Nav
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</NavBar>
```

So when I click on the `NavDropdown.Item`, a blue color appears and I want to change that to another color.

[image]

So I went to bootstrap's files, and I found in `_dropdown.css`:

```
.dropdown-item {
    //some properties here...
    &:active {
        //some other properties here
    }
}
```

so to change that color, I ovverided in my .css file like this:

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

but it looks like it has no effect...

So does any body know where am I wrong ?

Comment: btw I am wrapping `<NavDropdown.Item>` into `<Link>` because I don't want to use href

Comment: Could you provide us with a working code snippet, please?